# После получения данных ajax не срабатывает

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Не впервый раз задаю подобный вопрос, но ощущение что jquery открывается мне вновь и вновь, где-то полсе аякса функция on() срабатывает, а где-то нет.
Честное слово не пойму :)
Получаю список фоток и пытаюсь удалить, не выходит. Перезагружаю и фотографии легко удаляются.

```
$("#gallery .loaded .photo-actions").on("click", ".loaded-remove", function () {
    var idphoto = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/algo/set/del_user_photo.php',
        data : { id: idphoto }
    });
    $(this).parent().parent().hide('slow');
return true;
});
```

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы хотите.
"Где-то полсе аякса функция on() срабатывает, а где-то нет."
AJAX же внутри on, как он может сработать после или не сработать? Напишите подробнее.
И вот это 
"$(this).parent().parent().hide('slow');"
мало кому что скажет без кода разметки .)

Comment: Вот здесь обсуждали данный пример http://hashcode.ru/questions/223214/jquery-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%83

Но после того как данные пришли на страницу аяксом, клик перестает срабатывать.

Comment: давайте ещё разобъясним про `on()`

селектор элемента (**у вас это `#gallery .loaded .photo-actions`**)должен быть "статичным". т.е. он не должен загружаться аяксом, второй параметр `on()` должен быть селектором потомка в дереве dom (у вас '.loaded-remove') т.о. если вы загружаете элемент `#gallery` то надо указывать вышестоящий элемент